# Get related element data from only selected radio buttons to array

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm in school and working on a project using ASP.NET Core MVC. I'm still rather green, so I apologize if this info is out there somewhere, but I wasn't able to quite find what I was looking for, or at least an example that I could understand. I'm just trying to figure out if I'm on the right track with what I'm trying to do. Some background:

On the server side I have two types of objects: combatants and encounters. Combatants have an ID, name, etc. Encounters have an ID, name, and a list of integers.
I am getting a list of combatant objects from a database. I'm then passing that list to the view. Once there I want to dynamically display the name of each combatant in the list, along with a radio button for each one. The idea is that the user will select only the combatants they want out of all the ones displayed.
Once those selections are made I want to get the ID property of the selected combatants and store those in a list that will then be used to seed the list of integers for the Encounter object before it is finally stored in the database.
I'm concerned I've gotten too far in the weeds as I'm rather unfamiliar with JavaScript and passing the data back and forth from controller and view. So I guess I want to know if what I'm doing makes sense, or if I'm doing it all wrong. Here is my dynamic HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered mr-3 ml-3">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Select?</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- Dynamic code for creating the table rows from the list -->
                    @foreach (var combatant in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@combatant.CombatantName</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="@combatant.ID" value=@combatant.ID></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I imagine I need to use JavaScript on the client-side to grab the checked radio buttons and then create a list that will hold the combatant.ID values of the selected ones. The only way I can think to do this seems rather obtuse, but maybe that's just the way it is:
I take the list of combatants passed from the model and convert it to JSON which can then be used in JavaScript. When I dynamically create the HTML, I assign the element ID and value of the radio button element to combatant.ID (as seen in the above code) Then I loop through the JSON-ized list of combatants (comList) to get the ID value and then only add the checked ones to the new combatants array:

JavaScript

```
const combatants = [];
let comLen = comList.length
for (let i = 0; i < comLen; i++)
{
   let id = comList[i.ID]
   if(document.getElementById("id").checked)
   {
      combatants.push(getElementByID("id").value)
   }
}
```

I then send that array back to the controller. I guess my follow up question would be if everything so far is reasonable, how do I get that array back to the controller where it can be put in the database?

Comment: You don't need javascript for this, but if you do use it, you'd want an ajax call to the controller.  Whether you use ajax or a standard form post, you'll need 1) a <form>, 2) a model in the controller that binds to the form fields used.  You should probably use checkboxes instead of radio buttons (radio buttons are usually used for a single selection of many options...) Your controller model would be a list of combatants with an added bool that reflected the state of the checkbox.  (false=unchecked, true=checked)  So create a class for "combatant" which includes name, id and checked(bool).

Comment: You'd then have a List<Combatant> Combatants in your controller that you'll use a for loop with indexes to iterate to display the form fields/labels.  Include your controller/view model to get more specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm concerned I've gotten too far in the weeds as I'm rather
> unfamiliar with JavaScript and passing the data back and forth from
> controller and view. So I guess I want to know if what I'm doing makes
> sense, or if I'm doing it all wrong.

Actually, whatever you have planned and described completely making sense and can be achieved either using strongly type class or javascript as well. Surprisingly, you don't need to know javascript for your implementation but if you want to use javascript deterministicly then you can check few tutorial as plenty of resources available .

In addition to this, what [@pcalkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744568/pcalkins) has explained  is also correct. Thus, I am showing you, how it can be implemented using viewModel concept.

Let's assume, you have following Combatant list and you want do get on your server only the selected Combatant details once you submitted to controller:

[image]

Model:

```
public class Combatant
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? CombatantName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

Note: I am using IsChecked  property to filter the selected value once submitted.

View Model:

```
 public class CombatantViewModel
    {
        public List<Combatant>? Combatants { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var combatantVirtualList = new List<Combatant>()
            {
                new Combatant() { ID=1,CombatantName="Combatant-A", IsChecked = false },
                new Combatant() { ID=2,CombatantName="Combatant-B", IsChecked = false },
                new Combatant() { ID=3,CombatantName="Combatant-C", IsChecked = false },
                new Combatant() { ID=4,CombatantName="Combatant-D", IsChecked = false },
                new Combatant() { ID=5,CombatantName="Combatant-E", IsChecked = false },


            };

            var model = new CombatantViewModel();
            model.Combatants = combatantVirtualList;
            return View(model);
           
        }
```

Note: To load checkbox list I am seeding few demo data which you would pull from database.

View:

```
@model YourProjectName.ModelFolder.CombatantViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Combatant Check Box List";
}
<h4>Load Combatant And Post Selected List</h4>

<hr />
<form asp-action="SubmitCombatantSelectedValue" asp-controller="CheckboxSelectedValue" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mr-3 ml-3">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Select?</th>

        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Combatants?.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td> @Model.Combatants[i].CombatantName</td>
                <td><input  asp-for="@Model.Combatants[i].IsChecked" /></td>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Combatants[i].ID" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Combatants[i].CombatantName" />

            </tr>

        }
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit To Controller</button>
</form>
```

Controller For Form Submit:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SubmitCombatantSelectedValue(CombatantViewModel combatantViewModel)
        {
            var combatantSelectedValueFromView = combatantViewModel.Combatants?.Where(ifSelected=> ifSelected.IsChecked == true).ToList();

            return Ok(combatantSelectedValueFromView);
        }
```

Note: I am using [Linq query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/write-linq-queries?source=recommendations) to find the selected checkbox value.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [tag-helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-7.0), [ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [LINQ Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/)  you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#additional-resources)